# Elements height same as other element height while being wider and absolute positioned

Tags: html, css

Here's though one.

I have following code which places div as part of background. Scrolling wont show up if user has screen resolution = 1024px.

The problem is that i need #background div to be same height as #content.

Is there any way to achieve that using **only css**?

```
<body>
    <style>
        body {
          margin:0px;
          background: yellow; 
        }
        #background { 
            overflow: hidden; 
            position: absolute; 
            z-index: -1;
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100%; /* ??? */
        }
        #background > div { 
         background: blue;
            margin: auto;
            width: 1108px;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        #content {
            background: red;
            width: 1004px;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="background"><div><!-- this will not affect page scrolling if its width id greater than browsers window --></div></div>
    <div id="content">
        lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br />
            [...]
    </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

thanks for downvotes and comments. i found answer myself. all you need is to wrap everithing with `<div style="position: relative">`

**EDIT2:**

or just give `position: relative` to `<body>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i introduced `id="parent"` div and made this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/napascual/8zFCP/), then I added `top:0`, `bottom:0` hack to `#background`div to adjust the height to `#parent` div.

I also changed the width in the example fiddle, so it can be seen working:

```
<body>
    <style>
    body {
        margin:0px;
        background: yellow;
    }
    #parent{
        position:relative;
    }
    #background {
        background-color:black;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute; 
        z-index: -1;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
    }
    #background > div {
        margin: auto;
        width: 1108px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #content {
        background: red;
        width: 1004px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    </style>
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="background">
            <div><!-- this will not affect page scrolling if its width id greater than browsers window -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br />
            [...]
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Is this what you're reaching?

Comment: sorry. no accept to that. i figured it out first. and you don't need bottom:0; top:0; to make it working.

Comment: @seler sorry seler, but you need to put that hack on the code, otherwise, when you put more code inside `#background` its height will grow!
(Test the solutions first!!)

Comment: @Nacho sorry nacho i dont need any content in `#background` that's why it's named _background_. i tested your solution. Adding top:0;bottom:0; changes nothing.

Comment: @seler I still have the satisfaction for making your knowledge grow... if you need this hack in the future, you know how it works.

Comment: @Nacho it's working in FF, Chrome, Opera without top:0;bottom:0;

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:** *The problem is that i need #background div to be same height as #content.*

If you want #background to always be the same height as #content, simply put #content div inside of #background div.